# Is it correct to filter observables using flatMap and filter?

Tags: java, android, reactive-programming, rx-java, rx-android

Using a contrived example to illustrate my question, I have an Observable of a type of composite object:

```
Observable<Category>

public class CategoryPayload {
     public List<Category> categories;
     // other meta data and getters
}
public class Category {
     public Integer id;
     // other meta data and getters
}
```

I need to filter out certain categories based on id so I end up doing something like:

```
    Observable<CategoryPayload> categoryObservable = service.getCategoryPayload();
    // use flatMap to transform the Observable into multiple
mSubscription.add(
    categoryObservable.flatMap(new Func1<CategoryPayload, Observable<Category>>(){

         public Observable<Category> call(CategoryPayload categoryPayload){
              return Observable.from(categoryPayload.categories);
         }
    }).filter(new Func1<Category, Boolean>(){
        public Boolean call(Category category){
             return category.id != SOME_BANNED_CATEGORY_ID;
        }

     }).toList())
     .subscribe(mObserver);
```

Please forgive the contrived code. I am really just trying to understand whether it is a correct use of RX to flatten out my observable and then filter it in the way that I am doing above.

Comment: Assuming you actually want to end up with `Observable<Category>` at the end and not `Observable<CategoryPayload>`, this seems reasonable.

Comment: @Vulcan you do not need a stream to invoke flatMap see http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/rx/Observable.html#flatMap(rx.functions.Func1)

Comment: @Vulcan I am not on the latest Java version so maybe that explains the differences. I am sad to say I cannot use lamdas.

Comment: @MattBall I threw a toList() in at the end. I want to end up with Observable<List<Category>>

Answer (score 3):

You are using Rx.Observable filter method to filter over a List. This is an anti-pattern because Lists are Iterables, which are the dual to Observable. Hence what you really want is a filter function for Lists, instead of converting an Iterable to Observable.

You can either use Guava's filter functions for collections, or Kotlin's built-in functions for Iterables (would require rewriting in Kotlin), or Xtend's equivalent to Kotlin's (would require rewriting in Xtend), or writing the manual mutation (with for loop) in Java.

Overall, you would `.map` over `Observable<CategoryPayload>` and inside the map do the filtering over `List<Category>`.

Answer (score 3):

I don't see any problem with using RxJava. If you expect a single result from `getCategoryPayload()` or you don't care if multiple lists of categories get into the same aggregated list, then your example is okay.

```
mSubscriptions.add(
    service.getCategoryPayload()
    .flatMapIterable(p -> p.categories)
    .filter(c -> c.id != SOME_BANNED_CATEGORY_ID)
    .toList()
    .subscribe(mObserver)
);
```

Otherwise, If you want to keep the payloads intact but trim the categories, you can use any fluent Iterable API (Guava, IxJava):

```
mSubscriptions.add(
    service.getCategoryPayload()
    .map(p -> {
        Ix.from(p.categories).filter(c -> c.id == SOME_BANNED_CATEGORY_ID).removeAll();
        return p.categories; // or just return p;
    })
    .subscribe(mObserver)
);
```